# Forcing a (generic) value type to be a reference

Tags: c#, reference, value-type

I have a struct with some fields. One of the fields is of a generic type. The generic type could be **either a reference type or a value type**.

I want to force that it is stored as a reference internally, to avoid that the struct gets too large.

```
struct Foo<T>
{
  T field; // should be a reference
}
```

I know I could use `object` or `T[]`, but both is awkward. Isn't there something like a generic Reference type?

```
struct Foo<T>
{
  Reference<T> field;
}
```

Yes, sure, I could write my own. But I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: I don't understand how that solves the problem. Suppose S is a large value type. Then Foo<S> is *the same size* as S. If the user is fine with the performance of S then why wouldn't they also be find with the performance of Foo<S>? Boxing S - whether you box with object or your own custom boxing class - will use *more* space overall because you'll have to have space for the instance of S *and* space for the box.  Boxing S will use *more* time because it takes time to box and unbox S.

Comment: And keeping S in a reference type will add considerable pressure to the garbage collector if there are a lot of them. Can you explain why you think this is any kind of win, because this seems to me like making a bad situation - that is, the perf cost of a large struct - far, far worse.

Comment: @Eric: I don't want that the struct becomes to big. structs should be small in memory usage. There are other fields in this struct and it is already on the upper limit. If T would be a Guid or an even bigger value type, the resulting struct would be to big.

Comment: OK, then why is Foo a struct in the first place? Make Foo a class. Problem solved. Or not. You haven't said what the *problem* is so it is impossible to do more than guess. You don't get any gain without a corresponding cost; you can trade more time spent copying (by using a struct) or more collection pressure (by using a class) but the only way to avoid both is to have less data in the program in the first place. What is the cost you need to avoid, copy cost or collection cost?

Comment: @Eric: I want Foo to be a struct (for various reasons, one is to avoid null), T to be a reference, because of total size of Foo. Always. Even if T would be a value type. Call it "explicit boxing". Type safety would be nice (the accepted answer isn't). That's it. Isn't it clear now?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger You still didn't explain why it is a problem that Foo may be a large struct. Is it replicated in many places ? Is it passed (thus probably copied) around many times ? Some other reason ? To put it differently: You say foo will become too big. "Too" big for what ? How big is "too" big ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to be absolutely sure any Value Type is boxed, store it in an object field and use a property to enforce the generic constraint; ie:

```
struct Example<T>
{
    private object obj;
    public T Obj
    {
        get
        {
            return (T)obj;
        }
        set
        {
            this.obj = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be noted however, depending on how you're using this structure, that the raw memory of the struct may differ for two identical values since structs aren't interned and boxes will have different pointers. the Equals method will still work for managed comparison so this is only a concern for specific managed->native transitions.

Comment: I was thinking Tuple was a ValueType, but apparently it's not, so I recommend thecoop's answer.

Answer (score 11):

Define T to be a class.

```
struct Foo<T> where T : class
{
  T field; // Now it's a reference type.
}
```

Comment: no, I don't want to force that T is a class. When T is a value type, I want that it is stored as reference.

Comment: you could simply box `field` into an object type [which is the only gud solution that comes to my mind]. what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I don't want that the struct becomes to big. structs should be small in memory usage. There are other fields in this struct and it is already on the upper limit. If T would be a Guid or an even bigger value type, the resulting struct would be to big.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Tuple<T1>` to hold your value type variable (`Tuples` are classes in the BCL)

```
struct Foo<T>
{
    Tuple<T> field;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

and if you want it to be an instance:

```
where T : new()
```

Comment: It will always be an instance or null ref. you use new() if the object of type T needs instantiation via default constructor of type T at  runtime.